# Apache Camel - aggregator to space out requests, but not queuing requests

Tags: apache-camel

I have route which when sent a message invokes a refresh service

I only want the service to be invoked at most every 1 minute

If the refresh service takes longer than 1 minute (e.g. 11 minutes) I don't want requests for it to queue up

The first part: every 1 minutes is easy, I just create an aggregator with a completionTimeout of 1 mins

The part about stopping requests queueing up is not so easy and I can't figure out how to construct it

e.g.

from( seda_in )
.aggregate( constant(A), blank aggregator ) 
.completionTimeout( 1000 )
.process( whatever )...

if the process takes 15 seconds then potentially 15 new inoke messages could be waiting for the process when it finishes. I want at most just 1 to be waiting for however long the process takes. (its hard to predict)

how can I avoid this or structure it better to achieve my objectives?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would be interested in seeing the Throttler pattern, which is documented here http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html

Hope this helps :)

EDIT - If you are wanting to eliminate excess requests, you can also investigate setting a TTL (Time to live) header within JMS and add a concurrent consumer of 1 to your route, which means any excess messages will also be discarded.